# Connect to Mysql database using php Fail

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi so i am trying to make a login system using mysql and php but i constantly get the error

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in E:\PHP_Runner\php\root\process.php on line 10

The user is created as seen in the [image: picture] Any suggestions/help?

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$username = stripcslashes($username);
$password = stripcslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

mysql_connect("localhost",$username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db("users");

$result = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'")
        or die("Failed to query database" .mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password){
echo "Login success !! welcome".$row['username'];
}else{
    echo "Failed to login";
}

?>
```

Comment: I hope you don't intend on going live with this, right?

Comment: btw; you're using the same variables for the credentials and from the POST arrays.

Comment: @Fred-ii- will be first to exploit it! ^_^

Comment: @PriyeshKumar *lol*, no I'm not like that.

Comment: nah im just trying to learn how php and mysql interact

Comment: and also noticing that you're using the same `users` for both db and table. You using both as the same name or you chose the wrong db?

Comment: Think of it like a bank. You buy a safety deposit box and get a key, that key will open the box, not the bank. The bank is the DB, the box is your table. So change `mysql_connect("localhost",$username, $password)`... or make sure you are passing the database user in your form (sounds insecure though) (passwords also should not be plain text)

Answer (score 0):

To connect to mysql db phpmyadmin or any interface you will need to have mysql login credentials which is not a user login credentials this is usually set at the installation of mysql or you will be using the default. Now this set credentials will replace `mysql_connect("localhost", $TheSetUserNameForMysqlDb, $TheSetPasswordForMysqlDb)` I hope this help

> Which I don't recommend using the default

Answer (score -2):

mysql connect should be something like

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root", ""); // if you use phpmyadmin in localhost. here root is the defualt admin username of mysql and default password is empty.
```

Comment: `mysql_connect("localhost",$username, $password)` - what am I not grasping from their code? I think you're the one who missed something that I said in comments.